# Multiply list of pure functions by list of scalars?

Tags: list-manipulation, pure-function

I am trying to write a function that returns a list of pure functions. The last step in the function, is to multiply the list of pure functions by a list of scalars (i.e. matrix multiplication). When I try to evaluate the resulting functions, it does not work.

**Code**

```
calcShapeFunctions[nnpe_] := Module[
   {m, xiCoord, etaCoord, p, c},
   m = Array[
     Function[{xi, 
        eta}, {1, xi, eta, xi*eta, xi^2, eta^2, xi^2*eta, xi*eta^2, 
         xi^2*eta^2}[[#]]] &, nnpe];
   xiCoord = {-1, 1, 1, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0};
   etaCoord = {-1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0};
   p = m[[1 ;; nnpe]];
   c = Array[Through[p[xiCoord[[#]], etaCoord[[#]]]] &, nnpe];
   Return[p.Inverse[c]];
   ];
```

**Incorrect Output**

```
Through[calcShapeFunctions[3][x, y]]
```

returns:

> {(1/2 Function[{xi, 
>          eta}, {1, xi, eta, xi eta, xi^2, eta^2, xi^2 eta, xi eta^2, 
>           xi^2 eta^2}[[1]]] - 
>       1/2 Function[{xi, 
>          eta}, {1, xi, eta, xi eta, xi^2, eta^2, xi^2 eta, xi eta^2, 
>           xi^2 eta^2}[[2]]])[x, 
>     y], (1/2 Function[{xi, 
>          eta}, {1, xi, eta, xi eta, xi^2, eta^2, xi^2 eta, xi eta^2, 
>           xi^2 eta^2}[[2]]] - 
>       1/2 Function[{xi, 
>          eta}, {1, xi, eta, xi eta, xi^2, eta^2, xi^2 eta, xi eta^2, 
>           xi^2 eta^2}[[3]]])[x, 
>     y], (1/2 Function[{xi, 
>          eta}, {1, xi, eta, xi eta, xi^2, eta^2, xi^2 eta, xi eta^2, 
>           xi^2 eta^2}[[1]]] + 
>       1/2 Function[{xi, 
>          eta}, {1, xi, eta, xi eta, xi^2, eta^2, xi^2 eta, xi eta^2, 
>           xi^2 eta^2}[[3]]])[x, y]}

**Desired Output**

```
Through[calcShapeFunctions[3][x, y]]
```

should return:

> {1/2 - x/2, x/2 - y/2, 1/2 + y/2}

**Further Thoughts**

Assuming we can get this to work, how would I go about obtaining the derivatives of the pure function with respect to one of its independent variables (xi and eta)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with the [last question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22627/121) on which I believe this one is based, it may be simpler to use a single function rather than a list of functions.

To understand my code you will need to know that:

- You can manipulate a `Function` with `Part` just as you would any other expression
- [`Part` always wraps element sequences with the original head of the expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2450/121)

I chose to use `Slot` (`#` and `#2`) because it makes this manipulation much simpler, though it would be possible with named parameters with more work.

Other notes:

- I made output of the `calc` function to be a single function as well, simplifying both the code and the application of it
- I eliminated `p` as it appeared to be a copy of `m`
- `With` is use to evaluate certain parts of the output `Function`

The code:

```
calcFn2[nnpe_] := 
 Module[{m, xiCoord, etaCoord, p, c, xi, eta}, 
  m = {1, #, #2, # #2, #^2, #2^2, #^2 #2, # #2^2, #^2 #2^2} &;
  m = m[[{1}, ;; nnpe]];
  xiCoord = {-1, 1, 1, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0};
  etaCoord = {-1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0};
  c = Array[m[xiCoord[[#]], etaCoord[[#]]] &, nnpe];
  With[{ic = Inverse[c], mev = m}, mev[##].ic &]
 ]

calcFn2[3][x, y]
```

> ```
> {1/2 - x/2, x/2 - y/2, 1/2 + y/2}
> ```

Comment: This is a perfect solution, exactly what I was looking for. My only question is could you explain what's going on when you call `m = m[[{1}, ;; nnpe]];`? I'm confused on how `Part` is working there.

Comment: More perspicacious than mine. But for `Derivative` to work on `xi` and `eta` (`#1` and `#2`), won't you need something like `Evaluate[mev[#1, #2].ic] &` in the body of `With`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 `D[calcFn2[3][x, y], y]` does what I need it to do.

Comment: @Matthew  OK, if that's what you want.  `D[.., y]` calculates the derivative of the composition with respect to `y`, not the derivative of `calcFn2[3]` with respect to `eta` per se though, which would be `Derivative[0,1][calcFn2[3]]`.  For instance, `Derivative[0,1][calcFn2[3]][1,2]` or `Derivative[0,1][calcFn2[3]][x-y,2y]` could not be done by simply substituting `D[.., y]`.   Of course, in each case, it's possible to make `D` work one way or another.

Comment: @Michael I actually missed the bottom section of the question.  I'll have to consider that.

Comment: @Matthew I knew that part would be confusing; I tried to help by linking to [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2450/121) but I guess that wasn't enough.  (Please don't take that negatively; I just have trouble explaining this sometimes.)  I should update the previous answer to make cases like this more clear.  I'll also think about how I may update this one, both to explain that method and to address Michael's valid concern.

Comment: @Matthew Please review the updated answer that is linked in this question and tell me if my application here becomes understandable.  If not I'll try again.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard That's perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @Matthew Okay, good. :-)  By the way, are you aware that you can both Accept and vote for an answer?  I ask because I notice that you have not voted for this answer, which I assume is an oversight, but thanks for the Accept.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I understand what you are saying. How would I implement your version? I tried adding the `Evaluate` command, but it did not work.

Comment: @Matthew I added an explanation to my answer - too long for a comment.

Answer (score 3):

First, to evaluate the functions embedded in `calcShapeFunctions[3]`, you could do the following:

```
calcShapeFunctions[3] /. f_Function :> f[x, y]
```

> ```
> {1/2 - x/2, x/2 - y/2, 1/2 + y/2}
> ```

But to find the derivatives, you need to alter how `calcShapeFunctions` function is defined so that the bodies of your `Function`s are evaluated and the part of the list of formulas is extracted (line 4):

```
calcShapeFunctions[nnpe_] := 
  Module[{m, xiCoord, etaCoord, (*p,*) c}, 
   m = Array[Function[{xi, eta}, 
         Evaluate@{1, xi, eta, xi*eta, xi^2, eta^2, xi^2*eta, xi*eta^2, xi^2*eta^2}[[#]]] &,
        nnpe];
   xiCoord = {-1, 1, 1, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0};
   etaCoord = {-1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0};
   (*p = m[[1 ;; nnpe]];*) (* same as p = m *)
   c = Array[Through[m[xiCoord[[#]], etaCoord[[#]]]] &, nnpe];
   Return[m.Inverse[c]];];
```

Then the derivatives can be done as follows:

```
calcShapeFunctions[3] /. f_Function :> Derivative[1, 0][f][x, y]
```

> ```
> {-(1/2), 1/2, 0}
> ```

```
calcShapeFunctions[3] /. f_Function :> Derivative[0, 1][f][x, y]
```

> ```
> {0, -(1/2), 1/2}
> ```

(Note: In `calcShapeFunctions`, the variable `p` was the same as `m`, so I replaced it.)

**Response to comment**

In response to the OP's request as to how I would modify Mr. Wizard's answer, I offer the following.  As I suggested in a comment, I would `Evaluate` the function body inside `With`:

```
calcFn2[nnpe_] := 
 Module[{m, xiCoord, etaCoord, p, c, xi, eta}, 
  m = {1, #, #2, # #2, #^2, #2^2, #^2 #2, # #2^2, #^2 #2^2} &;
  m = m[[{1}, ;; nnpe]];
  xiCoord = {-1, 1, 1, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0};
  etaCoord = {-1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0};
  c = Array[m[xiCoord[[#]], etaCoord[[#]]] &, nnpe];
  With[{ic = Inverse[c], mev = m}, Evaluate[mev[#1, #2].ic] &]]

calcFn2[4]
(* {1/4 - #1/4 - #2/4 + (#1 #2)/4, 1/4 + #1/4 - #2/4 - (#1 #2)/4, 
    1/4 + #1/4 + #2/4 + (#1 #2)/4, 1/4 - #1/4 + #2/4 - (#1 #2)/4} & *)
```

One can take the `Derivative` of the `Function`:

```
Derivative[0, 1][calcFn2[4]]
(* {-(1/4) + #1/4, -(1/4) - #1/4, 1/4 + #1/4, 1/4 - #1/4} & *)
```

And plug in expressions:

```
Derivative[0, 1][calcFn2[4]][x, y]
(* {-(1/4) + x/4, -(1/4) - x/4, 1/4 + x/4, 1/4 - x/4} *)
```

Or one can apply `D` to the expression `calcFn2[3][x, y]`:

```
D[calcFn2[4][x, y], y]
(* {-(1/4) + x/4, -(1/4) - x/4, 1/4 + x/4, 1/4 - x/4} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define your own operator that maps a scalar and a function to a function i.e. $\otimes: \mathbb{R}\times\frak{F} \to \frak{F}  $

```
CircleTimes[c_, f_] := (c f[##] &)
```

and use it like  c <kbd>Esc</kbd>c*<kbd>Esc</kbd> f to get:

```
f[x_]:=x
10 ⊗ f 
(* 10 f[##] & *)
```

And you can Thread over lists:

```
constants = RandomReal[1, 3];
functions = {Sin[#1]Cos[#2]&, Cos, Exp};
result = Thread[CircleTimes[constants, functions]]
(* {0.845413 (Sin[#1] Cos[#2] &)[##1] &, 0.835235 Cos[##1] &, 0.103793 Exp[##1] &} *)
```

You can easily get derivatives with `D` by naming the arguments:

```
D[result[[1]][x, y], x]
(* 0.845413 Cos[x] Cos[y] *)

D[result[[2]][x], x]
(* -0.835235 Sin[x] *)
```

`Derivative` is a little more picky, it doesn't handle ## (`SlotSequence`) like one would expect:

```
Derivative[1, 0][(Sin[#1] Cos[#2] &)[##1] &][x, y]
(* 0 *) 

Derivative[1, 0][(Sin[#1] Cos[#2] &)[#1, #2] &][x, y]
(* Cos[x] Cos[y] *)
```

I'd go with `D` that symbolically evaluates the nested functions to avoid further surprises.